# Зачем нужен веб-сервер для pixijs

Tags: javascript, pixijs

Начал читать документацию [клик](https://github.com/kittykatattack/learningPixi#settingup) и не смог понять. Зачем же обычному js фреймворку нужен веб-сервер. Как я понимаю, есть файл, который загружается пользователю (pixi.min.js). После мы просто вызываем функции этого фреймворка, объясните почему без веб-сервера ничего не работает. Я говорю только про локальное использование у себя на компьютере.

Comment: А каким образом файл загружается пользователю ? У пользователя же браузер. а браузер все загружает по протоколу http с ... web сервера

Comment: если я локально открываю у себя на компьютере главный html, то все должно подгружаться без сервера. Я только про свой компьютер говорю, локально

Comment: Свой, локальный, компутер тоже работает по HTTP, просто он в сети один. Он **может** загружать по особым, локальным протоколам (типа `file://`), но это отнюдь не равнозначный обмен.

Comment: Если вы все сслыки в документе напишите как file: то все должно конечно и без web-сервера заработать. просто так обычно никто не делает и поэтому в доке пишут что нужен сервер. А еще браузер может отказаться загружать скрипт по локальной ссылке, лучше это проверить и в любой непонятной ситуации ставить web-сервер.